# CORS request with Electron

Tags: cors, electron, fetch-api, zoho

I can't manage to make a CORS request from my electron app.
I have set the required *webSecurity*

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024, 
    height: 768,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
  });
```

then trying to get data from zoho servers

```
fetch('https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts\\?organization_id\\=12345',
            {
                method: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': "Zoho-authtoken 984fe68e7f564c6bs01ee9ffb1dsa140",
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            .then(_result =>{
                console.info("_result",_result);
            })
```

Headers I'm sending (from network tab), response is **400**

```
GET /api/v3/contacts/?organization_id\=12345 HTTP/1.1
Host: books.zoho.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
authorization: Zoho-authtoken 987984fe68e7f564c6bs01ee9ffb1dsa140
X-DevTools-Request-Id: 21105.4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) basic-electron-react-boilerplate/0.7.0 Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Electron/1.8.8 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB
```

this request works when I **curl**

> curl https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts\?organization_id\=12345 
>   -H  'Authorization: Zoho-authtoken 984fe68e7f564c6bs01ee9ffb1dsa140' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: I tried a bunch of things I found online, but nothing helped. Now I just set up a express server on main electron script and it acts as router for my requests. But would love to figure out how to do this inside browser

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-features", "OutOfBlinkCors");
```

Comment: That's great! Keep in mind that ```webSecurity: false``` is still required.